# How to remove "http://" from domain name inside view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I remove "http://" from beginning of a URL inside view in an AngularJS app?

I have URLs in database like:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com
example.com
```

but I only need to show

```
example.com
```

inside the view.

Comment: @Joe I work on limited URLs, I don't have https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This deals with HTTP and HTTPS or any other URL. It uses the built-in URL class, which will handle all of the things you haven't thought of correctly.

```
  app.filter('domain', function () {
    return function (input) {
      try {
        var url = new URL(input);
        return url.hostname;
      } catch (DOMException) {
        // Malformed URL. Return original (or something else).
        return input; }
      };
    });
```

URLs that are correct and you  might not have thought of:

- http://example.com
- http://example.com:8000
- http://me@example.com
- file://example.com
- https://example.com
- http://example.com/some-path
- http://example.com?some-query-url

You may not need them now, but using the correct library function means your app won't break unexpectedly in future when someone tries to use it for something else.

Comment: I tried to use this filter in a project. it fails if the input URL doesn't have protocol in it. I know the question doesn't mentioned this condition.

Comment: On the line after the 'malformed url' comment, you could append a URL scheme and try again.

Answer (score 2):

use this filter in view

```
app.filter('domain', function () {
  return function (input) {
    var output = "",
    matches;

    var urls = /\w+:\/\/([\w|\.]+)/;
    matches = urls.exec( input );

    if (matches !== null) output = matches[1];
      return output;
  };
});
```

Comment: sorry for undoing acceptance, Joe showed a better way. I think others gonna need it

Comment: @Gordian Yes, I think it's better too